# What could be the cause that includes cause my collection to be empty in .NET core EF and what to do about it?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, in-memory

```
    protected override IQueryable<Car> GetEntities(CarsContext context)
    {
        return context.Cars
            .Include(x => x.Handlebar)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Horn)
            .Include(x => x.Dashboard)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Settings)
            .Include(x => x.Dashboard)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Radio);
    }
```

The above code is an example of my code in .NET EF Core 2.

Apparently when I use the includes the cars collection stays empty.
When I return only `context.Cars` I have a few 100 records.

I would expect that regardless if I use includes or not, I get the same results. If there isn't anything to include I would expect that Navigation property to be empty. **Is this assumption right?**

I already checked if there are relationships between the Cars and the navigation properties and confirmed this is indeed the case for some, but for others there aren't any. This could be the cause, but then again I want to allow some navigation properties to be `null`. **Should I change my code?**

It's worth to mention that I use **EF core 2.0.1 in memory storage**, since I started with tests only.

In a random test, just for checking, I also asserted all the navigation properties:

```
    //verify db is filled
    using (var context = _carsContextFactory.Create())
    {
        context.Cars.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
        context.Handlebars.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
        context.Horns.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
        context.Radios.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
        //Update: dashboard stays empty, not all are filled.
        context.Dashboards.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
        context.Settings.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
    }
```

Not all are filled.

Am I thinking wrong here? What could be the cause of this? Is it the empty `dashboards` in the context?

**UPDATE**:

I noticed a mistake in my code and one of the list in the includes does stay empty, what this means is that a required field of the `Car` is not correctly filled. What I still find very strange is that I don't get an exception, it just returns an empty list. **Is this normal behaviour?**

Comment: Can you include the code that checks for records in the `IQueryable`? Perhaps you should convert your `IQueryable` to a list (using `toList()`) ?

Comment: Pretty sure that is not the problem. I use `ToList()` somewhere indeed. The fact that is does work with only `Cars` proves enough right?

Comment: If Cars is the only entity, where it does not work - why don't you show us your entity configuration for `Car`?

Comment: I am not realy using Cars, do you know if there is something like `DefaultIfEmpty` here? I think that would answer my question.

Comment: First, what exact EF Core version are you using? Second, can you provide a repro (mcve) because I can't reproduce with standard many-to-one optional relationships test entities in EFC 2.0.2

Comment: @ivan I'll try and workout a reproduction later on!

Comment: @IvanStoev I updated my question, it seems some includes were empty, still wondering why I don't get any exception though.

Comment: I guess EF Core is relying on FK constraint being enforced in the database. But this is just speculation, only EF Core designers can answer that. Consider posting a question to their issue tracker.

Comment: I came in exactly the same problem with ef core in memory. Did you solve this problem anyway?